# Apache TomCat - APEX

Tags: tomcat, oracle-apex

Apache TomCat (version unknown)

Business Objects 4.1

APEX 4.4.3

On one server we hold TomCat and Business Objects.  APEX uses the TomCat as well.

After an infrastructure change to our Cloud the Business Objects Adaptive Processing Server (APS) has been consistently resetting itself about every 1.5 hours.

So, the Java Heap size was doubled on the (APS) and the TomCat.  All its done is increase the resetting time period e.g. to 3.5 hours.

From what I have read it could be the TomCat garbage collection procedure that might be out of sync.

Could APEX affect the garbage collection?

At this moment its clutching at straws trying to work out what is going on.  If I can eliminate APEX then the focus goes back to Business Objects and TomCat.

If you have any hints please pass them on.

Cheers

Comment: Yes I was truly clutching at straws with this.  its nothing to do with APEX or TOMCAT.

In Business Objects i.e. the Central Management Server (CMS), there is a database and it had a lock on one of its tables.  I killed the lock on the table and all is fine.  Whew!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was truly clutching at straws with this. its nothing to do with APEX or TOMCAT.

In Business Objects i.e. the Central Management Server (CMS), there is a database and it had a lock on one of its tables. I killed the lock on the table and all is fine. Whew!